# Rails gem searchkick returns false results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have the Teacher model, and I am using the searchkick for this model. The first problem is when I search for a particular teacher, if the teacher is in model, it will not only return that teacher but also the rest of the teachers in my model. I did some research on the internet and couldn't find the solution for my case. Therefore, I really need your help guys.
Here are some of my files, just in case you need to see them, and I think you do.

**teachers_controller.rb**:

```
class TeachersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_school
  before_action :find_teacher, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
  end

  def search
    if params[:search].present?
      @teachers = @school.teachers.search(params[:search], fields: [{fullName: :exact}])
    else
      @teachers = []
    end
  end

  def new
    @teacher = @school.teachers.build
  end

  def create
    @teacher = @school.teachers.create(teacher_params)
    @teacher.save
      redirect_to(@school)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @teacher.update(teacher_params)
    redirect_to(@school)
  end

  private

  def find_school
    @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
  end

  def find_teacher
    @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
  end

  def teacher_params
    params.require(:teacher).permit(:firstName, :lastName, :middleName, :department, :school_id)
  end
end
```

**search.html.haml**:

```
.text-center
  / No search results announcement/notification
  - if @teachers.blank?
    %h2 Xin lỗi, hệ thống chúng tôi không có thông tin về giảng viên mà bạn muốn tìm.
  - else
    - @school.teachers.each do |teacher|
      %h2= link_to teacher.to_s, school_teacher_path(@school, teacher)

%br/

.text-center
  = link_to("Trang Trước", school_url(@school), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs")
  = link_to("Trang Chủ", root_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs")
```

**teacher.rb**:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :ratings

  searchkick word_start: [:firstName, :lastName, :middleName]

  def name
    "#{lastName} #{middleName} #{firstName}"
  end

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :schools do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
    resources :teachers do
      collection do
        get 'search'
      end
    end
  end

  resources :teachers do
    resources :ratings
  end

  root 'schools#index'
end
```

Comment: is there any fields `fullName: ` hope it would be `name`

Comment: Can you run it on console using `some_school.teachers.search('<teacher name', fields: [{fullName: :exact}])` and copy the output here

Comment: word_start: [:firstName, :lastName, :middleName] why you are using it it will search show all results if anything match on these fields

Comment: @RajarshiDas, yes, I have just added the column fullName into the teacher table, but it still gives me the same result.

Comment: after reindex and remove `word_start ` by restarting can you try plesae

Comment: @RajarshiDasa, yes, I tried to do it, but if I remove the word_start, when I type the exact name of teacher, it doesn't return that teacher. Moreover, when I type the first name or just the last name, it will return all the teachers.

Comment: @KinaanKhanSherwani, I tried to type what you suggest in my rails console, but the console didn't response and it just get stuck.